# Can't create new rails project- ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm completely new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails, and trying to get my feet wet in it. Just installed Ruby and ROR on Win 10 64 bit, and from the command prompt seem successfully:

```
c:\>ruby -v
ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [x64-mingw32]

c:\>rails -v
Rails 5.0.1
```

However, I can't create a project, it returns the following:

```
c:\>rails new demo

Using tilt 2.0.5
Using sqlite3 1.3.13
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.7.0.1
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/nio4r-1.2.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nio4r (1.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nio4r -v '1.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So the two major errors seem to be:

1) `Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

I thought that would be resolved by installing DevKit, at https://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/ but no cigar

2) C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
    C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError)

I have no idea this error. `C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe` is the correct path to Ruby on my system. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: This probably means you don't have all you need to build in your system. This is a common problem with Windows and this is one of the (many) reason why I suggest people to avoid Rails develpment in this OS.

Comment: I would suggest you re install rails using the Rails installer GUI, which will pretty much do all the intallation for you  http://railsinstaller.org/en

Comment: If you want to continue with this, I suggest trying to install the gem using the command `gem install nio4r -v '1.2.1'`, if that does not work, follow those errors to see what you need to do next.